# Youtube Video in DispForm.aspx

Tags: list-view, video

I have a list in sharepoint 2013, each list items have a link to youtube video.
how can I show that video in DispForm.aspx of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply modify your custom form of Displaying item using SharePoint Designer or else you can place rendering JavaScript file(CSR/JSLink).

**Designer Option**
In SharePoint Designer you can go to your list and then create custom form and then you can specify the value of video as `src` of iframe.

Refer this [MSDN - SharePoint 2013: Building Custom Forms](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx) article

**JSLink Option**
You can edit that display form page and then specify the JSLink to that webpart with custom rendering applied.

Refer this [Customize List Form Fields in Display Form (DispForm.aspx) using JS Link in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/customize-list-form-fields-in-display-form-dispform-aspx-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013-2/)

In both the option you only need to set the `src` of iframe or embed code of youtube link.